# Renew the Linux, Restore to the new

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems

I'm new to Linux. My Ubuntu 13 is now meeting problem such the CPU rate is about 100% ever time and the System Drive Disk Usage is full. I think the virus is attacking my computer. Are there any ways i can do to restore it to the previous point or to make it new?

Comment: If your system drive is full, then your cpu will go to 100%.  This is not a virus, you need to clear some files.  Try this to see where the space is being used:  `sudo du -shx /*`

Comment: Well, When i checked the disk for the first time, It is used up to 86%, after only a few minutes it raise up to 94% and my System is very slow. However, i'm going to use you command! :D

Comment: Is the "System Drive Disk" your root (`/`) partition? What is taking up the CPU? You can check by running `top`. You can be almost certain it is not a virus, there are _very_ few Linux viruses and none of them are really harmful.

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot exclude that your computer has caught some malware, I doubt very much that your problems are caused by a virus. Or do you have other evidence, probably suspicious files? (In fact, most malware tries to act inconspicuously, and not alarming you with much activity.)

You should first try to find out which process is running amok on your system, e.g. by running `top` in a terminal window. It should show you the processes causing the most CPU load at the top. Your system drive is probably being filled with log data from this berserk process. You should look at typical places for that:

```
ls -l $HOME/.xsession-errors
```

and

```
ls -lSr /var/log/
```

are candidates for growing log files and could give you some hints. (`-lSr` means: 'l'ong listing, sort by 'S'ize, 'r'everse order, which means you get a long list of all files in `/var/log/` with the largest ones listed last. )

Next step would be to find out what caused that process to misbehave. But that depends on the process. Only if that does not work I would think about reinstalling.